# Finding the sum of a series till $n$ terms

Tags: sequences-and-series

Series:
5, 11, 19, 29, 41
Find the sum of the series up to $n$ terms.

Well the method that comes to my mind is to find the nth term of the sequence, and then find their summation. I use the basic formulas, such as sum of series $n^2$, $n^3$, etc.

My question is whether their is a shorter method to achieving this, or maybe just an alternate method.

Comment: Nope, I'm pretty sure the only way to do it is as you mentioned

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference table for the sequence is given by

${\color{red}5}\;\;\;\;  11 \;\;\;\; 19  \;\;\;\;29$

$\;\;\;{\color{red}6}\;\;\;\;\;8\;\;\;\;10$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;{\color{red}2}\;\;\;\;\;2$

$\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;\;0$,

so $\displaystyle a_n={\color{red}5}\binom{n-1}{0}+{\color{red}6}\binom{n-1}{1}+{\color{red}2}\binom{n-1}{2}$, and therefore

$\displaystyle \sum_{k=1}^{n} a_{k}={\color{red}5}\binom{n}{1}+{\color{red}6}\binom{n}{2}+{\color{red}2}\binom{n}{3}=5n+6\cdot\frac{n(n-1)}{2}+2\cdot\frac{n(n-1)(n-2)}{6}=\frac{n(n+2)(n+4)}{3}.$

Comment: Ummm.... *scratches head* What exactly happened here? I understood until the difference table. What exactly happened after that? This method seems nice, please explain it?

Comment: If the left diagonal of the difference table is given by $c_0,c_1,\cdots,c_l,0,0,0,\cdots$, then $a_n=c_0\binom{n-1}{0}+c_1\binom{n-1}{1}+\cdots+c_l\binom{n-1}{l}$.  Using a hockey-stick identity, this gives $\sum_{k=1}^{n}a_k=c_0\binom{n}{1}+c_1\binom{n}{2}+\cdots+c_l\binom{n}{l+1}$.

Comment: And in the last step, how did you expand it?

Comment: The last step uses the sum along a diagonal of Pascal's triangle:  $\binom{k}{k}+\binom{k+1}{k}+\binom{k+2}{k}+\cdots+\binom{n}{k}=\binom{n+1}{k+1}$.

Comment: Still no idea how you got that expression from it?

Comment: For example, in the last term of my answer, I'm using $\binom{0}{2}+\binom{1}{2}+\binom{2}{2}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{4}{2}+\cdots+\binom{n-1}{2}=\binom{n}{3}$ (where the first two terms are 0, so can be ignored).

Comment: So it basically works out to be the same thing. Just a more concise way of representing it.

Answer (score 2):

Let $\displaystyle  S=5+11+19+29+41+\cdots+T_{n-1}+T_n$

$\displaystyle S=5+11+19+29+41+\cdots+T_{n-1}+T_n$

$\displaystyle S-S=5+\underbrace{(11-5)+(19-11)+(29-19)+(41-29)+(T_n-T_{n-1})}-T_n$

$\displaystyle\implies T_n-5=6+8+10+12$ upto $n-1$terms  $=(n-1)\{2\cdot6+(n-2)2\}=(n-1)(n+4)$

$\displaystyle T_n=5+n^2+3n-4=n^2+3n+1$

$\displaystyle\implies S_n=\sum_{r=1}^nr^2+3\sum_{r=1}^nr+\sum_{r=1}^n1$

Comment: Umm yeah but that's the same way that I did it?

Answer (score 1):

If you look at your data using any plotting device, you should notice that the points you give perfectly align along a parabola $$1+3n+n^2$$ Then, the elegant solution given by lab bhattacharjee.

Comment: So after finding the nth term that is the only way?

Comment: lab bhattacharjee's solution is extremely elegant to reach this point. After, it is easy. My way is very lazy !

Comment: That is the way we were taught this, but I find it easier to find it out by simple observation. Anyways thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For a slightly different way of getting the pattern, note that the sequence of first differences is $6,8,10,12,\ldots$ and thus the second differences are constant. So the sequence is quadratic i.e. $a_n=An^2+Bn+C$. Then \begin{align}
a_1&=A+B+C=5,\\\\
a_2-a_1&=3A+B=6,\\\\
(a_{n+2}-a_{n+1})-(a_{n+1}-a_n)&=2A=2,
\end{align} which we may backsolve to obtain $(A,B,C)=(1,3,1)\implies a_n=n^2+3n+1$.

As an alternative to summing the series with standard formulae, start by considering the ordinary generating function $A(x)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^n$. Since $a_{n+2}-2a_{n+1}+a_n=2$, we may write

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+2} x^{n+2}&=A(x)-(a_2 x^2+a_1 x)=A(x)-(11x^2+5x) ,\\
&=2 \sum_{n=1}^\infty x^{n+2}+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n+1} x^{n+2}-\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n x^{n+2}\\
&=\frac{2x^3}{1-x}+2x\cdot\left(A(x)-5x\right)-x^2 A(x)
\end{align}

from which we deduce 
\begin{align}
A(x)
&=\frac{1}{x^2-2x+1}\left(11x^2+5x+\frac{2x^3}{1-x}-10x^2\right)\\
&=\frac{x^3-4x^2+5x}{(1-x)^3}\\
&=5x+11x^2+19x^3+29x^4+41x^5+\ldots.
\end{align}
[WolframAlpha](http://po.st/pW1Fou) bears out the series expansion in the final line.

To use this to obtain the partial sums $S_n=\sum_{k=1}^n a_n$, observe that 
$$\sum_{n=1} S_n x^n =\sum_{n=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^n a_n x^n=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{n=k}^\infty a_k x^n=\sum_{k=1} \frac{a_k x^k}{1-x}=\frac{A(x)}{1-x}$$ where in the second line we have reversed the order of summation, allowing us to sum the geometric series and recognize $A(x)$. So $S_n$ is given by the $n$-th coefficient of $$\frac{A(x)}{1-x}=\frac{x^3-4x^2+5x}{(1-x)^4}=\frac{2}{(1-x)^4}-\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}-\frac{1}{1-x}.$$ The partial fractions can be expanded by the (negative) binomial series, yielding 
\begin{align}
S_n &= 2\binom{n+3}{n}-\binom{n+1}{n}-\binom{n}{n}\\
&=\frac{1}{3}(n+3)(n+2)(n+1)-(n+1)-1\\
&=\frac{1}{3}n(n+2)(n+4)
\end{align}
as the formula for the $n$-th partial sum. As a check, note that this begins as $5,16,35,64,\ldots$ which are indeed the first few partial sums.

Now, this was a fairly algebra-heavy route. But I find it has the advantage of being systematic and rather direct; it's also rewards your knowledge of Taylor series over clever guessing. For instance, note that the observation that $A(x)/(1-x)$ gives the partial sums of the coefficients of $A(x)$ didn't depend on on what $A(x)$ was. So if we're willing to do the work of getting $A(x)$ for a given sequence, then all that remains is to expand $A(x)/(1-x)$ appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

No one thought of this I guess , but I need further insight into this

$5+11+19+29+41+.....$

$= 5+(10+1+20-1)+(30-1+40+1)+.....(10(n-2)-1+ 10(n-1)+1)$

I assumed for once that n is an odd number , if n is even , it'll leave me with either (10(n-1)-1) or (10(n+1)+1), so let's take n as odd.

We get ,

$5+10+20+30+40+.....+10(n-1)$

$= 5+10{1+2+3+4+.....(n-1)}$

$= 5+10[{(n-1)/2}*(1+n-1)]    [S=(n/2)* (a+l)]$

$= 5+10n(n-1)/2$

$= 5+5n²-5n$

$=5( n²-n-1)$

Now this doesn't even satisfy the equation so correct me where I'm wrong and how this should have been done , by eliminating 1 and turning them into factors of 10